# Django: change a model and migrate?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, migration

I've added an IntegerField to a Django model, but I just can't migrate it.
I type:

```
python3 migrate my_app
```

and it tells me that there are no migrations to apply. Then, of course, my admin page outputs an error because it can't find the new column! Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit: console output

```
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying jokes.0003_joke_no...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 179, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 77, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 702, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1868, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` first?

Comment: Yes, of course, no problems.

Comment: But did it create the migration?

Comment: Here's what I did next: commented out the integerfield, migrated it, works with no problems, uncommmented, made migrations, but now when I migrate, it's different. I edited the question, check it out.

Comment: You didn't provide a default value for the integer field. Django tries to put an empty string into this integer field for all the existing entries in your db. Provide a default value or make that field nullable.

Comment: My db is currently empty...

Comment: I seem to have solved it my replacing default='' with default=0. Weird...

Comment: I don't know why you think that's weird. '' is not a valid value for an integer field, 0 is.

Comment: Yes, but I have other integerfields with default values of '' and no problem...

Comment: @Antoni4040 Change the default value for that IntegerField to `default=0` as well. It will create errors during testing.